# S3 trigger Lambda throttling

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, concurrency, triggers, throttling

If I set reserved concurrency for lambda, will the trigger from S3 be lost?
Assume: I upload 500 files for the S3 trigger event and have 10 lambda reserved concurrency sets.

Answer (score 1):

From [Asynchronous invocation - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html):

> If the function doesn't have enough concurrency available to process all events, additional requests are throttled. For throttling errors (429) and system errors (500-series), Lambda returns the event to the queue and attempts to run the function again for up to 6 hours. The retry interval increases exponentially from 1 second after the first attempt to a maximum of 5 minutes. If the queue contains many entries, Lambda increases the retry interval and reduces the rate at which it reads events from the queue.

Some further references:

- [Error handling and automatic retries in AWS Lambda - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html)
- [Failure handling between S3 trigger and Lambda | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUADGtXlR5SECXdKFQairNqA/failure-handling-between-s-3-trigger-and-lambda)

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's beneficial for me. It provides me with more information.

Comment: In case I want to handler lambda invocation. Can I use SQS? My flow will be S3 > SQS > Lambda. What do you think about that?

Comment: That flow is perfectly fine. It will probably handle a long queue better than going S3 > Lambda.