# Handling High Volume CSV File Processing uploaded on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a use case where I need to process a CSV files uploadedto an AWS S3 bucket. The folder structure is organized by date and hour (yyyy/mm/dd/HH), and the files regularly uploaded throughout the day. My task is to process these CSV files as soon as they are uploaded and make an API call for each file's data. Currently, I have set up an AWS Lambda function to handle the processing. The Lambda function has a concurrency limit of 150, and it takes approximately 50 seconds to process each CSV file. The concern is that sometime there may be more than 1000 files uploaded simultaneously. My understaing is in this case first 150 file will be process by 150 instances of lambda and reamining file will be processed after their execution. Is there any possibility of files being missed to process by lambda function? If Yes Then What's the best approach to handle this scenario and ensure that all files are processed promptly without missing any? Any other AWS architechure?

I dont have contorl over the size of the files and SQS have size limit of 256kb. so S3-->SQS--> Lambda dont think works for me!

Comment: *"Is there any possibility of files being missed to process by lambda function?"* - not if you manage to have "free" invocations within 6 hours. Lambda retries throttled async invocations internally. And SQS would work for you without any problem (and more insight into the backlog of messages) because S3 does not put the file contents into the queue but only the "pointer" to the file, aka. bucket name, key, version id and other stuff. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75528225/2442804

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you. One more question: is there any chance of files being processed more than one time?

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Rarely, but it does happen occasionally.

Comment: @luk2302 So is it better to use S3-->SQS--> lambda or Is there a way to avoid the file being processed twice? because my use case must enforce file being processed once.

Comment: @luk2302  Not super experience with AWS. So great if you share: does setting up SQS serves any better purpose in my case? I just need to read the csv and make post API call.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a quick process for big files, lambda isn't the right service. You should use Glue job. This service is more powerful and has parallel processing.

If your files aren't complex, you can use lambda, but you need to use SQS for controlling your process and SQS Dead letter for handling any possible error on your lambda.